# Logstash worker dies with no reason

Tags: logstash

Using logstash 2.3.4-1 on centos 7 with kafka-input plugin I sometimes get

> {:timestamp=>"2016-09-07T13:41:46.437000+0000", :message=>#0, :events_consumed=>822, :worker_count=>1, :inflight_count=>0, :worker_states=>[{:status=>"dead", :alive=>false, :index=>0, :inflight_count=>0}], :output_info=>[{:type=>"http", :config=>{"http_method"=>"post", "url"=>"${APP_URL}/", "headers"=>["AUTHORIZATION", "Basic ${CREDS}"], "ALLOW_ENV"=>true}, :is_multi_worker=>false, :events_received=>0, :workers=>"", headers=>{..}, codec=>"UTF-8">, workers=>1, request_timeout=>60, socket_timeout=>10, connect_timeout=>10, follow_redirects=>true, pool_max=>50, pool_max_per_route=>25, keepalive=>true, automatic_retries=>1, retry_non_idempotent=>false, validate_after_inactivity=>200, ssl_certificate_validation=>true, keystore_type=>"JKS", truststore_type=>"JKS", cookies=>true, verify_ssl=>true, format=>"json">]>, :busy_workers=>1}, {:type=>"stdout", :config=>{"ALLOW_ENV"=>true}, :is_multi_worker=>false, :events_received=>0, :workers=>"\n">, workers=>1>]>, :busy_workers=>0}], :thread_info=>[], :stalling_threads_info=>[]}>, :level=>:warn}

this is the config

```
        input {
      kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "${KAFKA_ADDRESS}"
        topics => ["${LOGSTASH_KAFKA_TOPIC}"]
      }
    }

    filter {
      ruby {
        code =>
      "require 'json'
       require 'base64'

       def good_event?(event_metadata)
         event_metadata['key1']['key2'].start_with?('good')
       rescue
         true 
       end

       def has_url?(event_data)
         event_data['line'] && event_data['line'].any? { |i| i['url'] && !i['url'].blank? }
       rescue
         false
       end

       event_payload = JSON.parse(event.to_hash['message'])['payload']

       event.cancel unless good_event?(event_payload['event_metadata'])
       event.cancel unless has_url?(event_payload['event_data'])
    "
  }
    }

    output {
      http {
          http_method => 'post'
          url => '${APP_URL}/'
          headers => ["AUTHORIZATION", "Basic ${CREDS}"]
      }

      stdout { }
    }
```

Which is odd, since it is written to logstash.log and not logstash.err

What does this error mean and how can I avoid it? (only restarting logstash solves it, until the next time it happens)

Comment: Post ur lohgstash configuration along with no of worker threads config.

Comment: @ArijeetSaha added the config, how can I get the worker threads config?

Comment: Dumb question but how are the `${...}` placeholders resolved? Are you running this from a shell script or something similar?

Comment: The number of worker thread is a launch option (-w or --pipeline-workers)([source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.3/upgrading-logstash-2.2.html)) and by default is half of the available CPU cores ([source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.3/breaking-changes.html#_filter_worker_default_change)), unless you have a multiline filter, in which case it's one

Comment: What makes you think that your Logstash process dies? From the logs you've pasted, all I see are warnings, but there's no useful info on potential errors.

Comment: The only indication is that it says "status" => "dead and I can see that it stops processing. I have to restart the process to make it begin processing again

Comment: @Val I run logstash with --allow-env which then ${VAR} is taken as an environment variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1637) your ruby code could be causing the issue.  Basically any ruby exception will cause the filter worker to die.  Without seeing your ruby code, it's impossible to debug further, but you could try wrapping your ruby code in an exception handler and logging the exception somewhere (at least until logstash is updated to log it).

Comment: interesting, although there are rescues in the code, I've added the code to the question

Comment: What happens if message is blank or invalid json?  For example whatever generates it may make faux json by forgetting to escape quotes or something like that

Comment: essentially it could result in an exception, but that means there is a bug in the kafka-input-plugin :/ I'll try to debug this further to see if indeed there was a kafka event that was blank